# Thanks to what I'm able to reduce analytic functions in algebraic form?

Tags: polynomials, transcendental-equations

Usually I take this for granted, but lately I had an encounter with some infinitesimal calculus concepts from a computational point of view, Fourier transformations for the most part, and I can't wrap my head around what is the concept that makes possible to compute a transcendental function.

Typically you find a vague explanation about this that involves polynomials, and it's not really about computing analytical functions, it's about reducing or simplifying polynomial forms; also polynomials are already part of the simple algebra, there is nothing really analytic in something in a polynomial form, it's merely an expansion that tries to approximate the original behaviour, kinda like mimicking a certain behaviour.

So I guess that my question becomes, what are the principles that are used to transform a transcendental function into polynomials that are easy to compute ? In what point in time they were introduced/invented ?

There are other kind of expansions except the one based on polynomials ?

Comment: "what are the principles that are used to transform a transcendental function into polynomials that are easy to compute?" Are you familiar with Taylor series? "There are other kind of expansions except the one based on polynomials?" There are, for example, Pade approximants.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was expecting the Taylor series as a partial response, the point is that Taylor series are polynomials already, and the principles that transforms a transcendental functions into polynomials are not that clear to me by just looking at Taylor series. Taylor series look more like an applications of an idea rather than a self contained idea. It's like with numbers, the numbers are the result of the intervals idea, they represent something, but the underlying idea is about intervals, not about the numbers themselves. There must be a point in time were the idea behind this was born.

Comment: Taylor series are **not** polynomials.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's what they teached me, the Taylor idea is that from a function you get a series of polynomials and you can stop where you want on the expansion if you are ok with the approximation that you get. Please explain what is wrong with this .

Comment: The word "series" has a very specific meaning. You don't get a series of polynomials, you get a sequence of polynomials. The limit of that sequence of polynomials is not, itself, a polynomial --- it is a series, the Taylor series.

Comment: @GerryMyerson so I guess that I should rephrase my question in: how it's possible to compute a transcendental function using a series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand the question, but, here goes:

Given a (sufficiently smooth) function $f$, and a number $a$ in the domain of $f$, and a positive integer $n$, you can find a polynomial $p$ (which I should really write as $p_n(f;a)$) such that $p(a)=f(a)$ and $p'(a)=f'(a)$ and $p''(a)=f''(a)$ and ... and $p^{(n)}(a)=f^{(n)}(a)$ (that is, $p$ and $f$ agree at $x=a$, as do their first $n$ derivatives). Then it follows that $f(x)$ will be closely approximated by $p(x)$ for values of $x$ near $a$, and indeed "Taylor's Theorem with Remainder" gives you some idea of how good the approximation will be.

I don't know exactly when this was introduced, but it probably wasn't long after Newton & Leibnitz invented Calculus.

Before that, there were other methods for evaluating trigonometric functions, based on geometry; I'd refer you to texts on the history of math for details.

For more recent methods, you might be interested in [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC).

Comment: I was interested in pretty much both your first and second "sections" of your response, who invented this after Newton and Leibnitz and usually a geometric interpretation is always "handy" but you are not mentioning any reference in space or time so I don't know where to start. Regarding your last part I already knew about CORDIC algorithms, and I was about to open a new question about "how to express trigonometric function with CORDIC" since I have no idea where to start with it or with the Remez algorithm from a given trigonometric function.

Comment: "where to start" on the early stuff is, as I suggested, in books on the history of mathematics. Alternatively, type $$\rm taylor's\ theorem\ history$$ into Google, and see what comes up. For CORDIC, I've given a link. I also mentioned Pade approximants in an earlier comment --- have you followed up on that?

Comment: yes I followed that link, maybe I'm getting this wrong, but I would like to get an exemplification of the function not an approximation around some points; this would translate in a single function in my programming language of choice instead of "lookup table" that is probably not the best choice for me. That's what I mean by approximation of a function, it's the function rewritten in some computational friendly terms not just the approximation around some special points. I suspect that the Remez algorithm is able to generate something more than a lookup table.